# Why are the leading edges on the Boeing 787 made from aluminum?

Tags: aerospace-materials, horizontal-stabilizer, vertical-stabilizer

Why are the leading edges of the wings, horizontal stabiliser and vertical stabiliser and the engine's inlets made from Aluminium?

[image]

Comment: Because those surfaces are usually heated for anti-ice.

Comment: Because gold would be too expensive, too soft, and too heavy?

Comment: @mins:  And, of course, having a metal radome would defeat the purpose of a radome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are probably many factors in choosing aluminum vs. composites.

A big one is bird strikes. The leading edges are at the highest risk for this. Metal tends to absorb the impact better while retaining its strength, while composites would tend to delaminate and become much weaker. Resistance to in-flight hail must also be considered.

[image]
[image]
(Source [Left](http://www.moretimetotravel.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/P1130348.jpg), [Right](http://images.gawker.com/17um8exutpphmjpg/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800.jpg)) *Comparison of bird strike effect on aluminum and carbon fiber.*

Anti ice was also mentioned. These areas are heated with bleed air (or, for the 787, electrical elements) to melt or prevent any ice formation. Metals do much better at high temperatures than composites, which would tend to melt or lose strength. Metals are also able to conduct the anti ice heat better than composites.

Another factor could be manufacturing. These surfaces have a lot of curvature. Composite panels are often reinforced with honeycomb core, which is best on relatively flat surfaces. Of course composites could be made into these shapes, but the shape would limit material and configuration options. Metal is also easier to work with or repair than composites.

As far as choosing aluminum over other metals, it tends to be very light and cheap for its strength, has decent temperature capability for anti-ice, and when properly used is fairly resistant to corrosion or fatigue.

The nose does not have anti ice and must serve as a cover for the weather radar. Composites can be made relatively transparent to radar, but metal would tend to block the waves.

Comment: WRT anti-ice, metals also conduct heat much better than typical composites, making your anti-ice heating more effective.

Comment: Use [overexpanded Nomex cores](http://www.hexcel.com/Resources/DataSheets/Honeycomb-Data-Sheets/HRH_10_eu.pdf), and curvature is not such a problem anymore. Don't let that distract you; the answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: The ease of repairing aluminium is also a lot easier than composites. Composites work best when the whole structure is made from a single piece and you don't want to replace such large sections every time you have a bird strike.

Comment: Curvature isn't an issue when making bicycle frames out of composite materials, and bikes have much tighter curves than the leading edge of a large airliner.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: But do bicycle frames use sandwich shells? The ones I know are either tubes with a single solid wall, or they use a light wall with a foam core over the full diameter. Curvature is a real problem for sandwich structures, especially when you have curvature in two directions.

Comment: @Notts90: May I disagree? The experience from the Beech Starship was that composite structures are much easier to repair than metal structures. All it needs is a skilled person doing the work (NC-35 crash in Denmark). Also, with much less corrosion or fatigue problems there is much less to repair in the first place. Only impact is worse; that's why leading edges are made from metal.

Comment: @PeterKämpf the joy of the internet is the that you certainly can! I completely agree regarding fatigue and rust. For impacts though, I was lead to believe that composites meant always replacing the whole panel where metal had other options (not 100% what they are).

Answer (score 4):

There are a few reasons, the first is that the leading edge of the wing will be eroded in service by flying through dust, sand rain, hail etc. Metals are always typically used on such surfaces (termed an 'erosion shield') to reduce this effect, and also because minor damage can be polished out to keep the aircraft looking nice. Aluminum isn't the hardest waring material in this environment, but it is the lightest. Rotor blades would typically use Titanium or Nickel instead, as these harder metals work better in this more extreme environment.

The second reason is lightning strike; the leading edges of wings are common attachment points for lightning, so they are grounded to the airframes lightning return network. Making them from highly conductive metals can reduce the immediate damage caused as a result lightning attachment.

Comment: To make composites lightning-proof, a copper mesh is added to the layup. The real reason for metal leading edges is indeed impact tolerance. Once a leading edge is painted, erosion of that paint will not differ between metal and composite structures.

Answer (score 2):

Aluminum is used for erosion prevention. There is no composite solution which can withstand the erosion caused by water/rain or FOD (sand/grit). In addition, aluminum leading edges transfer heat better than composites, which allows for improved anti-icing.